# Solve $ c(n-1)^2 + n \leq cn^2$ for $c$

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to solve the following inequality

$$ c(n-1)^2 + n \leq cn^2 $$

and have been unsuccessful. I typed it into wolfram alpha and it said the solution was c = 1/2. However, it did not show an option to show all of the steps. I'm assuming wolfram is using some sort of approximation technique to solve it. Any help would be appreciated thanks...

I got as far as $$ cn^2 -2cn +c + n <= cn^2 $$
$$2cn - c >= n $$
$$ c>= n\div(2n-1) $$

Comment: Perhaps try expanding the left-hand side.

Comment: This is not an equation, it is an inequation / inequality.

Comment: 1) this is not an equation; 2) $c(n-1)^2+n \leq cn^2 \Rightarrow c(2n-1) \geq n \Rightarrow c \geq \frac{n}{2n-1}$. No any simpler result I can get.

Comment: @Asydot, where did the $c^2$ go?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I don't know what do you mean by $c^2$. There is no term including $c^2$ in OP's inequality.

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Comment: That final inequality should be $2cn - c \geq n$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I still need to know how wolfram managed to solve it and get a value of 1/2 for c...I need to know c in order to prove the asymptotically running time of a recurrence relation

Comment: I am not too sure how WolframAlpha got $c = 1/2$.  Note however, that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{n}{2n - 1}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I noticed that and I've tried using limits in the past for my proofs. However, my proff told us that limits were not allowed in our proofs.

Comment: Well, you could say that
$$\frac{n}{2n - 1} = \frac{1}{2 - (1/n)}.$$

Now, what happens to this quantity when $n$ becomes large?

Answer (score 1):

$$ cn^2 -2cn +c + n \leq cn^2 $$
$$2cn - c \geq n $$
$$ c \geq \frac{n}{2n-1} \text{if $n \geq \frac{1}{2}$ or } c \leq \frac{n}{2n-1} \text{if $n < \frac{1}{2}$} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$c(n - 1)^2 + n = c{n^2} + n(1 - 2c) + c$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: There shouldn't be a $c^2$ in here.

Comment: Indeed, corrected now.

Comment: $c(n - 1)^2 = c(n^2 - 2n + 1) = cn^2 - 2cn + c$.  Therefore, cancelling $cn^2$ from both sides of $cn^2 - 2cn + c + n \leq cn^2$, what do you get?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I updated my original post with how far I got initially.

Comment: $c \geq \frac{n}{2n - 1}$ is correct.  However, the inequality immediately before that is not.